# SoftLayer how can detach a Local Storage from VirtualMachine REST

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to detach a Local storage from a virtual machine but I get an error from the API.

This is want I do:

First, I get the Id of the storage

.../rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualDiskImages.json

```
0:  {
"capacity": 25
"createDate": "2016-09-15T05:28:16-05:00"
"description": "Disk 2"
"id": 21757115
"modifyDate": null
"name": "Disk 2"
"parentId": null
"storageRepositoryId": 2257588
"typeId": 241
"units": "GB"
"uuid": "0c7f6050-b8ff-431f-a500-f1e896e02c92"
} ...
```

Second, I try to detach the Local Storage from the VirtualMachine

Method: [DELETE] / [POST] / [PUT]

rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vm-id]/detachDiskImage.json

I tried the following request parameters:

1 -

```
   {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "imageId": "21757115"
            }
    }
```

2 -

```
   {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "id": "21757115"
            }
    }
```

3 -

```
   {
      21757115
   }
```

But I always get

```
{
"error": "You must provide a valid portable storage volume id."
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the next REST request to look for all the disk images that can be attached/detached:

```
http://[$username]:[$apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes.json
```

Method: GET

Then you can detach it using the next:

```
http://[$username]:[$apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[$virtualGuestId]/detachDiskImage.json
```

Method: POST

Body:

```
{
    "parameters": [
        1234567                
    ]
}
```

**virtualGuestId** is the virtual Guest id from which the disk image is going to be detached

**1234567** is the image id retrieved using getPortableStorageVolumes method

Note: The **getVirtualDiskImages** retrieves all disk images, even those that can’t be detached, so, in this case is better to use **getPortableStorageVolumes**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried [/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes.json] and I get my device information with the following attributes [id=21757115, name=..., capacity=..., uuid=, ...] Then I used the request [/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[$portableStorageVolumeId]/detachDiskImage.json], as POST and changing the [$portableStorageVolumeId] with the [id] value, Additionally, the body sends the same [Id] as parameter, why twice, no idea. Now I'm getting **"error": "Unable to find object with id of '21757115'."**

Comment: I updated my answer, please review it and make sure you're using correct ids.